# Efficiently finding the shortest queue

Tags: java

Say I have three classes, each of them has an int variable which represents a queue: q1, q2 and q3. All variables are at least zero and are constantly changing. Also each of the three classes has a boolean field: shortestQueue1, shortestQueue2 and shortestQueue3. I need a method, which compares q1, q2 and q3 at a given time and sets the corresponding shortestQueue variable to true and the other two to false. If two are equally small, the variable with the smallest number in the name is set(q1 over q2, q2 over q3).

Is there any other way instead of writing a lot of if/else statements?

Comment: Do you have already any code examples?

Comment: Provide your code. You can use a field with the length of the queue and compare them.

Comment: Well, I could write many if statements like: if(q1==q2&&q2<q3){shortestQueue1 = true}, and so on. But i would need 27 cases for that.

Comment: I have not written it as code yet, since I am looking for a shorter way

Comment: Do you check this often, and can new queues be added?

Comment: It runs in a for loop 3600 times. Each time there is 0,25 percent probability, that an event is happening. Each time when it happens, the shortest queue must be found and the corresponding variable (q1,q2 or q3) gets +1.

Comment: @keyser no additional queues cannot be added

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you don't really need 27 ifs for 3 variables ... 3 should do ...

Replace `System.outs` with whatever you need to do to your booleans.

```
    if(q1<=q2 && q1<=q3 ){          // q1 is the smallest
        System.out.println("q1");
    } else if (q2<=q3) {            // q2 is smaller than q3, we have tested q1 in the previous if
        System.out.println("q2");
    } else {                        // if neither q1 nor q2 is the smallest, it has to be q3
        System.out.println("q3");
    }
```